# Perimeter of traingle using python classes and objects

Tags: python, oop

Trying to find the perimeter of triangle but stucked in one issue.While running i am getting error as :

```
Triangle1.add_point(6, 1, 2)
```

File "/home/pravin/Desktop/oops/oop_drills.py", line 33, in add_point
    print(self.sides)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sides'
-4

```
import math


class Traingle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sides = []

    def add_point(self,*args):
        print(self.sides)
        self.sides = [[args[0], args[1]]]
        self.sides = [[args[0], args[1]]]

    def perimeter(self):
        self.L1 = math.sqrt((self.sides[1][0] - self.sides[0][0]) ** 2 + (self.sides[1][1] - self.sides[0][1]) ** 2)
        self.L2 = math.sqrt((self.sides[2][0] - self.sides[1][0]) ** 2 + (self.sides[2][1] - self.sides[1][1]) ** 2)
        self.L3 = math.sqrt((self.sides[2][0] - self.sides[0][0]) ** 2 + (self.sides[2][1] - self.sides[0][1]) ** 2)
        return self.L1 + self.L2 + self.L3

    def is_equal(self, args):
        if [self.L1 + self.L2 + self.L3] == [args]:
            return 'yes'


Triangle1 = Traingle
Triangle1.add_point(6, 1, 2)
Triangle1.add_point(2, 1)
Triangle1.add_point(1, 5)
print('ddd',Triangle1.perimeter())
```

Comment: You need to **call** your constructor: `Triangle1 = Traingle()`. After that you'll find you have another issue — you aren't actually adding points, you are just overriding `sides`, so you get an index error later.

Comment: Thanku @MarkMeyer how to vote you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?  Like mentioned in the comments you need () on the class and you need to append your points to the list.

```
import math
class Traingle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sides = []

    def add_point(self,*args):

        self.sides.append([args[0], args[1], args[2]])
        print(self.sides)


    def perimeter(self):
        self.L1 = math.sqrt((self.sides[1][0] - self.sides[0][0]) ** 2 + (self.sides[1][1] - self.sides[0][1]) ** 2)
        self.L2 = math.sqrt((self.sides[2][0] - self.sides[1][0]) ** 2 + (self.sides[2][1] - self.sides[1][1]) ** 2)
        self.L3 = math.sqrt((self.sides[2][0] - self.sides[0][0]) ** 2 + (self.sides[2][1] - self.sides[0][1]) ** 2)
        return self.L1 + self.L2 + self.L3

    def is_equal(self, args):
        if [self.L1 + self.L2 + self.L3] == [args]:
            return 'yes'


Triangle1 = Traingle()
Triangle1.add_point(6, 1, 2)
Triangle1.add_point(2, 1, 0)
Triangle1.add_point(1, 5, 0)

print('ddd',Triangle1.perimeter())
```